# stacking complex models that are prone to overfitting

Tags: cross-validation, conv-neural-network, stacking

I am working on a CNN (convolutional neural net) model to classify certain songbirds. I am using one CNN to classsify images of  the bird, and one CNN to classify audio sounds of the birds. I would like to combine the predictions made by both models. I however realize, even with usage of a validation set for both models and regularization, that either model might be prone to some overfitting. What is best practice to stack such models? Should one use a simple averaging to counter the inevitable overfitting of one of the models, or is best practice to use a seperate hold out set to tune the parameters of the stacked model? Any insight much appreciated.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem. I have 2 boosted models that perform well on the test set. If I stack them (using a linear model or for fun a tree) I get an extremely good fit on the training and much worse results on test. This is overfitting .. right=? ;) the simple average works best for me.

Comment: The overfitting is most likely due to the two cnn models. I think you should reduce their overfitting separately then stack them. Neural networks are prone to overfiffing.

Comment: So I moved my reply to the comment area, where it should be. I can only speculate since there is not much details about the models in the question. Usually the stacking/ensemble step is prone to eliminate possible overfitting, while on the other hand, nn models are easy to overfit by using too many layers or nodes without knowing it.